# .htaccess 301 redirect with query

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I know there are tons of these questions out there, but I still don't understand my issue.  Thanks to a miscellaneous link found on Google, we've found a bad link for this website.  I wrote a rewrite condition for it that is the below:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=&s=BARREEL+YOUR+OWN+BOURBON+RISKY+WHISKY+BARREL+PACK+$
RewriteRule ^/results.php$ http://www.thepartysource.com/express/item.php?id=28952 [R=301]
```

The '+' are in the actual link.  I've tried writing it as follows so that it doesn't count them as special characters:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=&s=BARREEL\+YOUR\+OWN\+BOURBON\+RISKY\+WHISKY\+BARREL\+PACK\+$
RewriteRule ^/results.php$ http://www.thepartysource.com/express/item.php?id=28952 [R=301]
```

The site still takes me to the wrong page and does not redirect me.  Can someone help with this please?  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The URL is

> /results.php?t=&s=BARREEL+YOUR+OWN+BOURBON+RISKY+WHISKY+BARREL+PACK+

Comment: Can you give examples of the URL(s) you're trying to redirect?

Comment: Is it always going to be `/results.php?t=&s=BARREEL+YOUR+OWN+BOURBON+RISKY+WHISKY+BARREL+PACK+
`?

Comment: Yes, that is the random link google is showing, and we have no clue where it got it from.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than getting out `RewriteRule`s you can use `Redirect` instead

```
Redirect 301 /results.php?t=&s=BARREEL+YOUR+OWN+BOURBON+RISKY+WHISKY+BARREL+PACK+ http://www.thepartysource.com/express/item.php?id=28952 [R=301]
```

However, it's worth noting, that Google has said you should Disallow/no-index search result pages on your site.

Comment: Thanks, but I had actually tried it this way too, and it just doesn't work for me.